# FTP Permissions in Linux (vsftpd)

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

Let's suppose I have a user called **user1** and his home directory is on: **/home/user1**. All files on that directory need to be **750** (*chmod -R 750 /home/user1*).

I installed vsftpd so I can manage my files easy, but there's one problem, if I chmod 750 all files inside that directory, I can't log in via FTP because of this error: **500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot ()**

To solve that error I have to chmod a-w the whole directory (*chmod a-w /home/user1*) but then I can't start some files that I have inside that directory (and that is fixed using 750 permissions).

I have 3 users so I have to jail them inside their home directories. Note that allowing writable root is not a good option, as I don't want users to get out of their home directories.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have writeable root directories then you need to enable the following option:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon